# Python Multiprocessing: Execute code serially before and after parallel execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

Novice here: I am trying to execute some code serially and then create a pool of threads and execute some code in parallel. After the parallel execution is done, I want to execute some more code serially.

For example...

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

print("I only want to print this statement once")



def worker(i):
    """worker function"""
    now = time.time()
    time.sleep(i)
    then = time.time()
    print(now, then)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(worker, [1, 1, 1])
        p.close()

print("Only print this once as well")
```

I would like this to return...

```
I only want to print this statement once
1533511478.0619314 1533511479.0620182
1533511478.0789354 1533511479.0791905
1533511478.0979397 1533511479.098235
Only print this once as well
```

However what it returns is this:

```
I only want to print this statement once
I only want to print this statement once
Only print this once as well
I only want to print this statement once
Only print this once as well
I only want to print this statement once
Only print this once as well
I only want to print this statement once
Only print this once as well
I only want to print this statement once
Only print this once as well
1533511478.0619314 1533511479.0620182
1533511478.0789354 1533511479.0791905
1533511478.0979397 1533511479.098235
Only print this once as well
```

So it seems to be running the print statements an additional time for each pool.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the observed behaviour, I assume you are on a NT/Windows Operating System.

The reason you see all those prints is because on Windows the [`spawn`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) start strategy is used. When a new process is "spawned", a new Python interpreter is launched and it receives the module and the function it's supposed to execute. When the new interpreter imports the module, the top level `print` functions are executed. Hence the duplicate prints.

Just move those print statement within the `__main__` and you won't see them again.