# Why does multiprocessing open up multiple pygame windows despite not processing anything pygame related?

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing

I'm making a chess program using a monte carlo tree search which will in the future be guided by a neural network. The problem at the moment is that despite all my efforts to maximise the efficiency of the system, the engine still takes 3 minutes to play through the 800 games required for the search. To combat this I have tried to implement some multiprocessing into the system so that it can play more than one game at once.

Unfortunately, despite being in a separate file which is imported into my main function, the multiprocessing still opens extra pygame windows with my menu system.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 400])


def play_game():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(3):
        game1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=play_game)
        game2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=play_game)
        game1.start()
        game2.start()
        game1.join()
        game2.join()
```

I'd expect this to open the pygame window at the beginning, then run the play_games after and leave the pygame code alone.
However, it opens two extra windows, one for each process. Why is this and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: `multiprocessing` requires that you have no top-level code outside of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.  Just move the two `pygame`-related lines into that block.

Comment: @jasonharper In my actual code, the pygame screen stuff happens in the main code, while the ai part of the program then gets imported in, so it's not so simple, although it does work int the test code. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You should probably use the threading library rather than multiprocessing.  Multiprocessing is *duplicating* your entire process.  But FWIW on my system I only get a single window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this encounters the same problem as you, and there is a solution there:

[Python Multiprocessing: Execute code serially before and after parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699040/python-multiprocessing-execute-code-serially-before-and-after-parallel-executio)

Basically you have to move `screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 400])` into `__main__` so that it only got executed once.

Hope this somewhat helps!